# Porque este patron con un negative look-ahead no consigue restringir estos reemplazos de la funcion re.sub()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, replace

Haciendo uso de un **negative look-ahead** `X(?!Y)`, revisar que NO este delante de la coincidencia, el objetivo es identificar las substring `"ellos"` que **no** tengan por delante alguna secuencia `((PERS)los` , y **si no hay ninguna entonces** que **reemplace** esa substring `"ellos"` **por** la string `"((PERS)ellos NO DATA)"`. En caso contrario no debe hacer ningún reemplazo.

```py
import re

# Example 1 :
input_text = "Ellos son grandes amigos, los cellos de ellos, pronto ellos se convirtieron en mejores amigos. ellos se vieron en el parque antes de llevar los viejos gabinetes, ya que ((PERS)los impresoras) eran aun útiles para la compañía ellos. Ellos son algo peores que los nuevos modelos."
# Example 2 :
input_text = "Ellos terminaron bastante rápido el diagrama de flujo"

input_text = re.sub(r"\(\(PERS\)\s*los", "((PERS)los", input_text)

#constraint_pattern = r"\bellos\b(?<!\(\(PERS\)/s*los)" # --> re.error: look-ahead requires fixed-width pattern
constraint_pattern = r"\bellos\b(?<!\(\(PERS\)los)"

input_text = re.sub(constraint_pattern,
                    "((PERS)ellos NO DATA)", 
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
print(input_text) # --> output
```

Usando este código, por algún motivo todas las apariciones de la substring `"ellos"` son reemplazadas por `"((PERS)ellos NO DATA)"`, pero en realidad tan solo las substring `"ellos"` que NO estén precedidas por una secuencia `"((PERS)los"` deben reemplazarse por `"((PERS)ellos NO DATA)"`

El objetivo realmente es obtener este **output**:

```
#correct output for example 1
"((PERS)ellos NO DATA) son grandes amigos, los cellos de ((PERS)ellos NO DATA), pronto ((PERS)ellos NO DATA) se convirtieron en mejores amigos. ((PERS)ellos NO DATA) se vieron en el parque antes de llevar los viejos gabinetes, ya que ((PERS)los impresoras) eran aun útiles para la compañía ellos. Ellos son algo peores que los nuevos modelos."

#correct output for example 2
"((PERS)ellos NO DATA) terminaron bastante rápido el diagrama de flujo"
```

Comment: @CandidMoe Enrealidad es por un tema de evitar tener ancho variable de caracteres, que limite a la aparición de "((PERS)los " , en este caso en el ejemplo 1 esta un caso en donde esa cadena si aparece "((PERS)los impresoras)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las expresiones regulares debe ser usadas con moderación, especialmente cuando hay alternativas más simples y fáciles de entender y mantener.

Por ejemplo, planteas un antes y después de un cierto texto en la entrada. No necesitas una expresión regular para dividir el texto; basta con `split()`

```
antes, despues = input_text1.split('((PERS)los ', maxsplit=1)
```

Ahora tienes el texto divido en dos partes, donde sólo te interesa trabajar en la primera. El reemplazo es elemental:

```
antes_mod = re.sub(r'^ellos|\Wellos', r" ((PERS)ellos NO DATA)", antes, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

y sólo queda rearmar la frase completa:

```
final = antes_mod + '((PERS)los ' + despues
```

¿Viste que simple es?

#### Demo

```
import re

input_text1 = "Ellos son grandes amigos, los cellos de ellos, pronto ellos se convirtieron en mejores amigos. ellos se vieron en el parque antes de llevar los viejos gabinetes, ya que ((PERS)los impresoras) eran aun útiles para la compañía ellos. Ellos son algo peores que los nuevos modelos."

patron = re.compile("([\w\(\)]+)")
m = patron.findall(input_text1)

antes, despues = input_text1.split('((PERS)los ', maxsplit=1)
antes_mod = re.sub(r'^ellos|\Wellos', r" ((PERS)ellos NO DATA)", antes, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
final = antes_mod + '((PERS)los ' + despues

print(final)
```

produce:

```
 ((PERS)ellos NO DATA) son grandes amigos, los cellos de ((PERS)ellos NO DATA), pronto ((PERS)ellos NO DATA) se convirtieron en mejores amigos. ((PERS)ellos NO DATA) se vieron en el parque antes de llevar los viejos gabinetes, ya que ((PERS)los impresoras) eran aun útiles para la compañía ellos. Ellos son algo peores que los nuevos modelos.

Process finished with exit code 0
```